# vb script if statement

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I want to edit a file with VB if the word that must to be in file isn't exist.
when execute this file, I want if condition was true do nothing but all file content was erase.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\file.html", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strSearchFor = "this word must to exist"

If InStr(1, strText, strSearchFor) > 0 then
    'do nothing
else
    strNewText = Replace(strText,"this word must to delete","this word must to exist" )
End If
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\file.html", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that becouse `strNewText` will be null when your condition true. and still replace the `strText` with your empty `strNewText`. 
 Keep your works in side the `if()`. so it will solve the Problem.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\file.html", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strSearchFor = "this word must to exist"

    If InStr(1, strText, strSearchFor) > 0 then
        'do nothing
    else
        strNewText = Replace(strText,"this word must to delete","this word must to exist" )

        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\file.html", ForWriting)
        objFile.WriteLine strNewText
        objFile.Close
    End If
```